# Open cv caer installation

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning, pip, computer-vision

I am trying to install caer a computer vision package but it is showing me a command error, my pip setuptools and wheel are up t date

```
pip install caer
Collecting caer
  Using cached caer-1.8.4.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\fortu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\fortu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1qa0dkkh\\caer\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\fortu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1qa0dkkh\\caer\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\fortu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-bzs1x8fk'
         cwd: C:\Users\fortu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1qa0dkkh\caer\
    Complete output (12 lines):
    c:\users\fortu\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\fortu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1qa0dkkh\caer\tools\cythonize.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
    [INFO] Writing _meta.py
    [INFO] Cythonizing sources
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\fortu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1qa0dkkh\caer\setup.py", line 267, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\fortu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1qa0dkkh\caer\setup.py", line 253, in setup_package
        generate_cython()
      File "C:\Users\fortu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1qa0dkkh\caer\setup.py", line 195, in generate_cython
        raise RuntimeError('[ERROR] Running cythonize failed!')
    RuntimeError: [ERROR] Running cythonize failed!
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: You have a problem with "cython" (pip install Cython). Maybe try to install/update this package beforehand and try again to install caer.

Answer (score 1):

I am also stuck in the same problem, It is caused because, maybe you have both the version in you box - Python 2.7 and Python 3.8.5

You can check python --version and python3 --version

So, the solution is: instated of
`pip install caer` , use

```
pip3 install caer
```

click here:[OpenCV error solution](http://mddn.in/#/home/detailContention/73543135109/Install-Python-and-OpenCV-in-Linux,-where-facing-probe-in-%27pip-install-caer%27)